# Is it possible to use the keyer more like a mask, adding effects to the keyed colour, rather than just making it transparent?

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, final-cut-pro, chromakey

I am playing with Final Cut Pro, and I was wondering how to use the Keyer function beyond just making a specific colour transparent on an overlayed video or image.

Say I had a video clip with portions of solid red which I want to make semi-transparent and display a blurred overlay of the video beneath it. Is this possible using a Keyer?